# How should you reference the JSON schema that a JSON object conforms to?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

There was another question similar to the one I am asking here ([Can you specify the schema URI on a JSON document that conforms to a JSON schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042566/can-you-specify-the-schema-uri-on-a-json-document-that-conforms-to-a-json-schema)) that was tagged as a duplicate of ([How to reference schema of json which is top level array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930439/how-to-reference-schema-of-json-which-is-top-level-array)), but I have nuanced variation of the question.

While it appears that there isn't anything in the JSON schema definition (https://json-schema.org/), is there a best practice that people follow in regards to indicating within a JSON object/document which JSON schema it conforms to (or is supposed to conform to)?

Would it be wrong to reference the schema using the $schema tag within a JSON object/document? It seems like referencing the schema it conforms to would also be a be a good way to "version" JSON objects/documents.

Comment: Your question would appear to be very similar to the closed question. However, the closed question is not a duplicate of the other question. I have voted to re-open the other question.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt there is an "acceptable" answer to this question.

There's nothing to stop you from using the $schema attribute as part of your own personal convention.

There is some real-world precedent to this. Some Azure quickstart templates use $schema to reference the JSON Schema they adhere to eg: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-azure-bastion/azuredeploy.parameters.json (Thanks to [Mark T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12161588/mark-t) for his comment)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
      "bastion-host-name": {
        "value": "GEN-UNIQUE-8"
    },
      "location": {
        "value": "southcentralus"
    }
  }
}
```

However, with a lack of official guidance we should perhaps just accept that the concept of *schema-instance* (as taken from XSD) is not a good fit for a lightweight definition language such as jsonschema.

I would be interested to understand your use-case where linking JSON instances explicitly with their schemas is a requirement.

Comment: We're persisting a variety of "things" as JSON objects. Over time, the schemas of the objects (attributes, structure, etc) are bound to change. It is unlikely that each time the schema changes, that all instances would get updated so it seems to make sense to  reference the schema that the object adhered to at the time it was created (essentially using the specific schema as a version identifier). I've had seen it done with some Azure stuff a while ago (a lot of azure configs as well as quick start templates were using $schema. I wasn't sure if it was just a MS thing or more universal

Comment: Here are examples of Azure quickstart templates that are using $schema to reference the JSON Schema they adhere to - https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

Comment: @MarkT can you link to specific examples? I cannot find any...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here is a specific example. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-azure-bastion/azuredeploy.parameters.json